# Fully "Kiosking" Chrome (capture and prevent default of C-w/t/n)

Tags: google-chrome, shortcut, kiosk, preventdefault

I need to prevent Ctrl-w, Ctrl-t, Ctrl-n from doing their default functionality.  I know removing user rights is frowned upon, but hear me out before casting judgement.

event.preventDefault() only works on lesser key combos like p, but n, t, and w are immune to client side javascript according to [javascript capture browser shortcuts (ctrl+t/n/w)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w).

I'm writing educational cloud software for kids 3-12, and I use Chrome's [Kisok mode](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=12bde481a208c4ca&hl=en) to limit their ability to screw around.  I have full control of the computers in question.  Are there hidden Chrome options / extensions / Windows tricks / something else that I can use to make the computer actually a kiosk instead of a "kisok"?

Also, I'm writing a cloud code editor using [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/) and I want to use emacs key bindings but I keep opening new windows when I try to go down a line.

EDIT clarification: It's Chrome only because that was the spec / we control the system, but it would be useful if anyone has thoughts on ff/o/ie

Answer (score 2):

Since you noted thoughts on other browsers would be helpful: [Opera's kiosk mode](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/) seems more powerful than Chrome's. I believe this would give the result you want: `opera.exe /kioskmode /nokeys http://your-url`

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the code is wedged in Chrome, and the testing alone would be two more hours than I'm willing to spend on this.