# Extjs KeyMap doesn't act on defaultEventAction but performs the default browser action

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Using ExtJS 4.1.1 even though in Ext.util.KeyMap i have set the defaultEventAction: 'preventDefault' and in the fn : function also i have set the e.preventDefault(); still it opens the new tab in chrome? **I just want the field to perform the action fn the keys are implemented for and not the default browser action of opening the new tab. How is this possible?**

```
    Ext.onReady(function () {

    var bcTextField = Ext.create('Ext.form.Text', {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        renderTo: 'console-output',
        emptyText: 'Enter Barcode/Accession Number',
        width: 200,
        margin: '0'
    });
    var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
        target: bcTextField.getEl(),
        binding: [{
            key: "t",
            ctrl: true,
            scope: this,
            defaultEventAction: 'preventDefault',
            fn: function (key, e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Ctrl + t was pressed.');
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the answer by Omnosis in this thread.. A detailed description about capturing such events is given. Hope it helps.

[javascript capture browser shortcuts (ctrl+t/n/w)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w)

Answer (score 0):

You need e.stopEvent();

This is what we use:

```
var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
    target: Ext.getBody(),
    binding: [{
        key: Ext.EventObject.F,
        ctrl: true,
        fn: function (key, e) {
            e.stopEvent(); //This stops the default behaviour ;-)
            //logic here...
        }
    }],
    scope: me
});
```

Comment: Well i tried to use the key T,
    `key: Ext.EventObject.T,
                        ctrl: true,
                        fn: function (key, e) {
                            e.stopEvent(); //This stops the default   behaviour ;-)
                            //logic here...
                            alert('Ctrl + t was pressed.');
                        }`

It opens the new tab of browser, which i don't wont.

Comment: It is intresting that if you use alert instead of console.log the event.preventDefault() not works, and opens a new tab.

Comment: yes, have the same problem, key: Ext.EventObject.T,
                    ctrl:true,
                    shift:true. And it still fires Chrome default behavior. Any working solution to this problem?