# Overriding shortcut keys in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a script that is supposed to open a section of a web page, and save changes on Ctrl + n and Ctrl + s respectively.  I got it working in IE, but it doesn't seem to work in Firefox and Chrome. Any ideas?

My override function.

```
function prevent(e)
{
try{e.stopPropagation();}catch(ex){}
try{e.preventDefault()}catch(ex){}
try{if (e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();
    else {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = false;
        e.keyCode = 0;
    }}  catch(ex){}
}
```

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7295508/212869 (or not as the case may be)

Comment: I am trying to avoid JQuery I already have looked at that one.

Comment: I was thinking more of the answers stating that some browser shortcuts cant really be overridden, also anything done in jQuery can be done in plain JavaScript

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have seen the same issue. Some browsers will not allow you to capture certain shortcuts. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7296303/1366887

Some key combinations are resticted in Chrome 4, but not in Chrome 3. Look here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-bugs/Ntc1byZXHfU

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 84) { 
    console.log("Hey! Ctrl+T event captured!");
    event.preventDefault(); 
  }
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 83) { 
    console.log("Hey! Ctrl+S event captured!");
    event.preventDefault(); 
  }
});
```

I have used this numerous times, and it has worked greatly.

Here is another rescource you can take a look at: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Without Jquery:

```
onkeydown = function(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'S'.charCodeAt(0)){
    e.preventDefault();
    //your saving code
  }
}
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kdaVT/) of it working.

Comment: I am having an odd problem with my code in firefox.  When I run your JSfiddle it works no problem, but when I add it to the js file on my site it still opens the new tab have you ever seen this before?

Comment: @wolfcall Are you sure you have th JS file linked? Also, this could be something to do with a new firefox if they have updated. Make sure you js is running.

Comment: My js is running I already thought of that i put an alert to display on load and it does launch. I have tried this file in firefox 15 and 20.

Comment: Don't worry about it I sort of figured it out.  My code to activate my save and new item functions for some reason cause it to happen anyway once commented out it works fine... took me two days to figure this out -.-'

Comment: Got more questions for you.  In Firefox do you have the alert function interfere with your prevent Default function

Comment: i am not really understand what you men?

Comment: If you run the JSFiddle link you gave me in firefox does it work with no changes?

Comment: Sorry with the Ctrl + N function not Ctrl + S

Comment: Surprisingly, the vanilla, non Jquery version still works in Chrome 81, while other methods fail. Also, it works 'only' when you use the capital key.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this in the future, the answer for current browsers is the following:

```js
if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'k') event.preventDefault()
```