# Override Cmd+Shift+[ in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

The goal is to override <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> in Chrome.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911785/overriding-shortcut-keys-in-firefox-and-chrome) is similar and was considered already, but unfortunately does not help. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> is not a prohibited combination, so it's unclear why it can't be overridden.

The code below overrides <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, but fails to override <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. Instead, the browser default for Chrome occurs instead.

How to override both <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pXbBZr?editors=1111

```
function initKeyboardEvents() {
   $(document).keydown(function(event) {

      // Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+[? Move to back.
      if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 219) {
         // Stop browser default.
         event.preventDefault();

         // Push to back.
         alert("push to back");
      }

      // Ctrl/Cmd+[? Move back one layer.
      if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.keyCode == 219) {
         // Stop browser default.
         event.preventDefault();

         // Push back.
         alert("push back one layer");
      }
   });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  initKeyboardEvents();

  console.log("document ready");
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding shortcut keys in firefox and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911785/overriding-shortcut-keys-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Comment: Heh, I can't actually find what that [shortcut does](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts).

Comment: @Lewis if you have multiple tabs open, it opens another tab

Comment: @TimVN the question is similar and was considered already, but unfortunately does not help. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> is not a prohibited combination, so it's unclear why it can't be overridden.

Comment: That’s cmd+t. Have you confirmed that it’s not a shortcut within MacOS?

Comment: @Lewis Cmd+t opens a new tab. If you have multiple tabs *already* open, try doing `Cmd+Shift+[`

Comment: @Crashalot any solution I'm also facing same issue