# Prevent Chrome's default keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, jquery-events

On the latest release of Chrome (Version 30.0.1599.101 m), how do I prevent the default behavior of keyboard shortcuts.

For example, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes the current tab. I want to assign this shortcut for user action, say to pop up alert box.

```
$('body').on('keydown', 'ctrl+w', function(e) {
    alert(Hello, world);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

On Chrome, this closes the tab. But works as expected in Firefox.

Is there a workaround to prevent Chrome's default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this link:  [javascript capture browser shortcuts (ctrl+t/n/w)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w/7296303#7296303)

In short, there are reserved keys that cannot be intercepted by javascript. You will need to use a non-reserved key combination instead.