# Cmd + y in MacOS opens history tab

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome

I need to set some event on cmd + y keys. It works, but always open history tab in chrome. How to prevent open history tab on mac using js in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery, Disable Browser Shortcut keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492793/jquery-disable-browser-shortcut-keys)

Comment: No, preventDefault() not working

Comment: Also stopPropagation

Comment: Please update your question with the code you're working with. Otherwise it's impossible to figure out what you're trying to do. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` to disable default action of key as action of `.onkeydown`

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.metaKey && e.key == 'y') {
    console.log('Cmd + Y pressed');
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Mac: Press ⌘ + <kbd>Y</kbd></div>
<div>Windows: Press  + <kbd>Y</kbd></div>
```