# How to prevent a user from using CTRL & + to zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to prevent the user from being able to press CTRL and plus to zoom out or minus for zooming in.

Is there any way of doing it ?

Comment: This is usually a built-in browser feature, so it's not likely something you can prevent.

Comment: there is not any way to stop reaction when the user press these keys?

Comment: What for? You can try to catch the key events and call `event.preventDefault`, but you always might be overruled.

Comment: @user3396302: even if you could stop the shortcut key there is usually a menu item like "View > Zoom In" that you could not prevent the user from clicking.

Comment: @Bergi: Tried that.  Doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/C5KTu/  You can't override browser behaviour.

Comment: Moreover, Ctrl+ is a usability feature of the browser.  You cannot stop the browser from doing things.  Moreover, you shouldn't want to, as it could prevent users with poor eyesight from viewing your pages and possibly end in lawsuit like the one the American Association for the Blind brought against Target.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I had expected something more like http://jsfiddle.net/C5KTu/4, but yes, it doesn't work. [Notice that *some* shortcuts *can be overridden*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7295508/1048572), that's why I proposed to try it out.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to prevent zooming in general (also with ctrl + mouseweel and touch-gestures on portable devices) you can simply add a meta-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

note that this could be disabled by browser-settings or -plugins and most desktop-browsers don't notice it anyway. the meta-tag can also be deleted using the dev-tools built in to most modern browsers.

it's not 100% safe - this just prevents your users from "accidently" zooming on your site.

Comment: I tried this in chrome, and I could still zoom.  http://jsbin.com/lakemavu/1 (try to zoom).  Here's the HTML: http://jsbin.com/lakemavu/1/edit

Comment: That doesn't prevent desktop browsers from scaling. NOR SHOULD IT. that meta tag isn't in w3c standards, and accessibility and useability _SHOULD_ allow users to zoom.

Comment: i think it is for the android zooming.

Answer (score 2):

No, that cannot be prevented as that's happening at the browser level. It's not doing anything to your code -- it's simply telling the browser to scale whatever it's rendering to xx% of its normal size when it displays it. You cannot control what the browser does with your page once it's rendered it -- you can only control what you provide it to render.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to block the key on your website using javascript

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 17) {
    //alert('your alert here');
    return false;
  }
};
```

the keycode is:

ctrl = 17
[+] (num) = 107
[-] (num) = 109

Comment: This doesn't work.  You can't block zooming.  P.S. There's `e.ctrlKey`.

Comment: Opened that link in Chrome and Firefox.  Was able to zoom.

Comment: If you pressing + out of numpad will not work. this keyCode corresponds of + in numpad.

Comment: Hmmm... guess the 2 `+` signs have different codes.

Comment: yes, if you like to test with other combinations, there's all the keys here http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx hope it helps :)