# How to capture user click in case of Ctrl + w or browser cross button

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/cezjbuky/

I have got the `window.onbeforeunload` event to prevent from closes like click on cross button on the browser or click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

How can I capture what the user has clicked on (whether user chose `Leave This Page` Or `Stay on this Page`)?

```
function warning(){
    if(true){


      return "You are leaving the page";
    }

}
window.onbeforeunload = warning;

function togooglepage()
{
    window.location = "www.google.co.in";
}

function toyahoopage()
{
    window.location = "www.yahoo.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can capture these events like that:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 87) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
  }
});
```

Here is a link for the [Key Codes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

for more information look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w)