# Shortcut Key commands in Chrome not preventing default action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, preventdefault

So I am writing a shortcut library and for the most part it works, except for the issue I found right off the bat is in Chrome (haven't tested other browsers since I'm on a chrome book) is that when pressing `ctrl+n` it creates a new browser window. Basically in jist my code checks if the current key selection is defined and if it is `preventDefault` and run the `exec` function of that command.

ie.

```
if(joinedKeys in commands.cmd)
    e.preventDefault();
    commands.cmd[joinedKeys].exec();
```

I've even tried just doing this-

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
//as well as window.addEvent...
```

Neither work. Any suggestions as to stop the default action of the browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7296303/5298696

> In Chrome4, certain control key combinations have been reserved for
>   browser usage only and can no longer be intercepted by the client side
>   JavaScript in the web page. These restrictions did not exist in
>   Chrome3 and are inconsistent with both Firefox3/3.5 and IE7/8 (on
>   Windows).

Comment: Hey thanks, so I'll have to make a note of this so that users won't try these combinators for the sake of civility, pretty funny how they up and take things away from us -_-