# how to prevent the default shortcut triggering from browser

Tags: javascript

Well, Im trying to make a custom shortcut for a web application. But I have a little problem ( I tried to find a solution but I only found the `preventDefault` and `shortcut.add` , I didnt understand well the second one)

I want to know how can I use the custom shortcut of my code without calling the browser shortcut. And if I use `shift key` the default shotcut wont disable the uppercase writing.

thx  a lot for the help, greetings from chile.

```
var menu_abierto=false;

$(document).on('keypress',function(e){

    if(e.which==69 && e.ctrlKey && menu_abierto==false){

      $('.btn-1,.btn-2 ,.btn-3').prop('disabled',true);    
      $('#lista-emergencias').show();
      MenuLateralIzq();
      listarEmergencias();
      menu_abierto=true;
    } else if(e.which==69 && e.ctrltKey){
      $('.btn-1 ,.btn-2, .btn-3').prop("disabled",false);
      $('#lista-emergencias ul li').remove();
      $('#lista-emergencias ul hr').remove();
      $('#lista-emergencias').hide();
      OcultarMenuIzq();
      menu_abierto=false;
    }

});
```

Comment: You have a typo btw `e.ctrltKey` instead of `e.ctrlKey`. And you don't need to check `booleans` like that. `menu_abierto==false` is the same as `!menu_abierto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default browser action and then come your custom action :

```
if( e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'INPUT' ){
   if(e.which==69 && e.ctrlKey && menu_abierto==false){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.btn-1,.btn-2 ,.btn-3').prop('disabled',true);    
        $('#lista-emergencias').show();
        MenuLateralIzq();
        listarEmergencias();
        menu_abierto=true;
    } else if(e.which==69 && e.ctrltKey){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.btn-1 ,.btn-2, .btn-3').prop("disabled",false);
        $('#lista-emergencias ul li').remove();
        $('#lista-emergencias ul hr').remove();
        $('#lista-emergencias').hide();
        OcultarMenuIzq();
        menu_abierto=false;
    }
}
```

Add `if( e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'INPUT' ){` if you want to disable this for inputs.

**Explanation :**

`e.target` mean the current selected element, `tagName` get the type of this element incase of input field that will return `INPUT`, `toUpperCase()` just to make sure that the `INPUT` string returned is on mode `UpperCase`, `!= 'INPUT'` mean if not input in other words if the element selected is not an input field then you can replace the browser shortcuts by the customs ones.

Check SO question/answers **[javascript capture browser shortcuts (ctrl+t/n/w)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w)**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 2 things:

#### [e.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Prevents further propagation of the current event.

#### [e.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Cancels the event if it is cancelable, without stopping further propagation of the event.

Comment: i have just one problem with your solution, when I want to use uppercase on the letter the shortcut  uses on an input field, the uppercase doesnt show util I release the shift key.

how can i fix this?