# Chrome - Disable ctrl+t shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, kiosk-mode

We are using `chrome 35.0`  via `kiosk mode` for client`s browsing on specific URL.

```
Chrome.exe --kiosk
```

But looks like it can be bypass by anyone when on opening new tab with shortcut `Ctrl +T`
We would like to disable it or any other creative idea to disable the ability to open a new tab by the user.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: See [javascript capture browser shortcuts (ctrl+t/n/w)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10933700)

Comment: We can't add any JavaScript to the websites. The solution should be on the browser or the OS

Comment: Windows, Linux, OSX all have easily googlable utilities/methods to redefine keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I need to redefine those keyboard shortcuts only for chrome, Is that possible ?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was not easy way to do that. And all the extentions did not work well..
So I found a creative solution:
On the extentions page, go to the bottom of the page and click shortcuts.

Define a new shortcut for an extention that do almost nothing or no any effect and set it to 'ctrl + t'

solved my problem !

Comment: Super! Thanks for this.

Comment: There is a new BlockKeys extension that does just this.

Comment: how to restrict window key or super key

Comment: Not working - by pressing ctrl+tab in input, instead of setting it Im switched to another tab