# What is the best way to identify if a KeyboardEvent is a built-in browser shortcut?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, cross-browser

I want to handle EVERY keyboard event that isn't a built-in browser keyboard shortcut and ignore EVERY event that is a built-in browser keyboard shortcut.

Is there a better way than manually hardcoding the complete list of shortcuts for every browser/OS combination?

Comment: have fun hardcoding them

Comment: [javascript capture browser shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w), it's not a complete duplicate but it's half the problem.

Comment: well... i'm off to cry