# Trapping command+shift+w mousetrap doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mousetrap

Is it possible to trap "command+shift+w" in mousetrap?
Cause I try to do

```
Mousetrap. bindGlobal('command+shift+w', (e) => {
    //some actions
});
```

and my browser(Chrome) window is getting closed. Could I prevent browser from closing on this shortcuts in some way only for specified page of my app?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following and it worked fine...

```
Mousetrap.bind('command+shift+w', function(e){ 
     console.log("command shift w")
});
```

If using windows make sure to use the windows key as opposed to command on mac.

If you are pressing CTRL SHIFT W , then that will shut the browser down. There are certain commands that are restricted to browser use only. See this post for more details [javascript capture browser shortcuts (ctrl+t/n/w)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w/7296303#7296303)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a 2nd argument to check which key combination fired the event

```
Mousetrap.bind('command+shift+w', function(e,combo){ 
 console.log(combo);
});
```

As mention by @Cavan Page, this works