# How to change the behavior of Ctrl+Backspace

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, textarea, electron

I'm trying to create a [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) IDE with Electron JS. The text-editing part is a `<textarea>` HTML element.

Right now, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> the entire script gets deleted because of what is considered a "word".

How can I change the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>? Is it a Chrome thing, or a JS/Electron thing, or an HTML thing, or a CSS thing?

---

I would like for each of the 8 Brainfuck characters to be treated as a word. With this behavior, a script that looks like this:

```
>>><<<+++---...,,,[[[]]]
```

would be completely deleted in 8 strokes of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Each block of 3 of the same character is a "word".

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you might try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w/7296303#7296303 to see if you can override or preventDefault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prevent the default behavior when a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is pressed:

```js
var ta = document.getElementById("ta");

ta.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {       // when a keydown event happens in the textarea
  if(ev.ctrlKey && ev.keyCode === 8) {              // check if control key is pressed along with the backspace (key code 8)
    ev.preventDefault();                            // if so, prevent the default behavior of this event
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
```

**Note:** After you prevent the default behavior, you can do whatever you like (add some text at the current cursor, delete some characters, ... anything you want).

Comment: I wanted to not have to reinvent the wheel by re-writing the ctrl+backspace behavior to be how I wanted it, but I just had to do it anyways. Thanks for your answer.