# Programmatically enter keystroke javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

What I want to do is to close a webpage using the shortcut control + W.

Can I write a piece of code that will simulate the shortcut (control+W).

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.key == "Control" && event.key == "w") {
        close();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think that event.key can ever be "Control" and "w" at the same time on a non-quantum computer. Also I think the OP wants to know how to "emit" that event instead of reacting to it.