# How to use windows shortcuts using Angular code

Tags: angular, typescript, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

In Windows laptop when we press "windows + h". default voice dictate will open.
But i want this shortcut button on single Angular button.
I want if i click on button that default voice dictate will open instead of pressing `windows + h`.
If anyone have any idea please suggest me.

I am exploring on that functionality but I did not get anything.

Answer (score 1):

Triggering OS shortcut keys is not possible in a browser as it would be a security risk.  I don't think you'll be able to do that *exactly*.

However there is a related [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API) that works in Chrome and Safari.  It does [not work in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=Web%20Speech%20API) and the experience varies by browser (Safari on Mac uses OS internals, Chrome seems to have its own engine).  Here's a generic article on using it: https://12daysofweb.dev/2021/speech-api/

A very-basic use might look like:

```js
function logSpeech() {
  const SR = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
  const recognition = new SR();
  recognition.lang = "en-US";


  recognition.onresult = function (event) {
    const transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
    console.log(transcript)
  }

  // in chrome this ends automatically
  recognition.start();
};
```

Comment: I tried web speech api but that punctuation is not working in Chrome. but its working in Microsoft Edge

Comment: I think I know why.  Edited with better cross-browser support (`window.webkitSpeechRecognition`).

Comment: i edited with tinymce editor but still its not working properly that why i shifted to default windows dictation but i am stucking in how to use 'windows + h ' as on single button

Comment: I'm not sure you can capture windows key shortcuts.  This answer may help you to though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w