# vue 3 key modifiers already in use by chrome

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to introduce key modifiers in my vue 3 app like the following:

```
<template>
<div id="shipmentViewDiv" 
       @keyup.ctrl.n="AddNewShipment()"
       @keyup.ctlr.plus="AddNewShipment()"
       @keyup.ctrl.o="OpenShipment()">
    // Rest of vue code.  Grid, buttons, menus etc
</div>
</template>
```

All of these shortcuts however just run the chrome shortcuts instead.  I didn't see much about restrictions of where exactly you could place these modifiers in the vue documentation here:

- https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling#key-modifiers

Is this possible to use shortcut keys like this that chrome is already using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `prevent` modifier to prevent the default browser behavior:

```
<div id="shipmentViewDiv" 
       @keyup.ctrl.n.prevent="AddNewShipment()"
       @keyup.ctlr.plus.prevent="AddNewShipment()"
       @keyup.ctrl.o.prevent="OpenShipment()">
```

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling#event-modifiers

Comment: I tried this but the same behavior is exhibited.  I'm not sure if I need to use these key modifiers in a different place but the code above is being navigated to by vue-router inside a `<router-view>`.  What your saying here does make perfect sense though.

Comment: @ColeW https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w/7296303#7296303 ‍♂️

Comment: @ColeW btw the event is keydown for the chrome shortcuts

Answer (score -1):

In web applications, certain key combinations are reserved by the browser for its own use, and it can be challenging to override these default behaviors. For example, Ctrl+N and Ctrl+O are commonly used by browsers to open new windows or open a file dialog, respectively.

To capture these key events in your Vue 3 application and prevent the default browser action, you can use the @keydown event instead of @keyup and call preventDefault() on the event object. Here's an example of how you might implement this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.31/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="shipmentViewDiv"
       @keydown.ctrl.n="addNewShipment($event)"
       @keydown.ctrl.o="openShipment($event)">
    <!-- Your content here -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    addNewShipment(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default browser action
      // Your logic to add a new shipment
      console.log('Adding new shipment');
    },
    openShipment(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default browser action
      // Your logic to open a shipment
      console.log('Opening shipment');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In this example, the addNewShipment and openShipment methods are called when the respective key combinations are pressed, and event.preventDefault() is used to stop the browser from executing its default action for those key combinations.

Comment: Instead of `@keydown.ctrl.n="addNewShipment($event)"` I did try `@keydown.ctrl.n.prevent="addNewShipment()"` but it just ended up doign the default chrome action which is to open a new tab/window.  Maybe this isn't exactly the same thing but it seems like it would be.